# change style of polyfill with HTML5

Tags: javascript, jquery, polyfills

I use polyfill with HTML5 as the following code and It works fine

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/webshim/1.12.4/extras/modernizr-custom.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/webshim/1.12.4/polyfiller.js"></script>
<script>
    webshims.setOptions('forms-ext', {types: 'date'});
    webshims.polyfill('forms forms-ext');
</script>

<body>
<input class="form-control" id="appointmentDate" type="date" name="appointmentDate" >
</body>
```

It generate date picker but It's not very nice

Is there any way to change to other style?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, what you mean with not nice. Here is an [example with 2 and 1/2 themes](http://afarkas.github.io/webshim/demos/demos/themes/themes.html) and [here are some configuration examples](http://fiddle.jshell.net/VNuct/show/). And last but not least here is a [datepicker configurator to configure it to your needs](http://afarkas.github.io/webshim/demos/demos/cfgs/input-date.html).

Due to the fact that everything is plain HTML and CSS you can improve styling your own.